# Could not find everit-org.json

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax

Trying to set up DataStax Astra in Spring Boot with Gradle but ended up with this error while following the [guide](https://github.com/datastax/astra-sdk-java/wiki/Spring-Boot-Starter-Quickstart#1-prerequisites). I am not sure on what I should do to fix this for Gradle. I tried `0.2.0-0.2.2` version

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema:1.14.0.
     Required by:
         project : > com.datastax.astra:astra-spring-boot-starter:0.2.0 > com.datastax.astra:astra-sdk:0.2.0 > com.datastax.stargate:stargate-sdk:0.2.0
```

File `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.cassandra'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.datastax.astra:astra-spring-boot-starter:0.2.0'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding (and using newer version)

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.everit.json/org.everit.json.schema
implementation group: 'org.everit.json', name: 'org.everit.json.schema', version: '1.5.1'
```

Old version maybe hard to download/pull to your PC.